# I got somes problems with v-bind, it's not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am learning VueJs but I kinda confused about v-bind! I have 4 buttons I want to have `active` class in the specific `button` when I click on that `button` but when I clicked on the button it looks like the method was not called! Example, If i click on `home` button the `home` button will have active class which will be changed to red. If i click on `watch` button the `home` button goes back to black and the `watch` button will be changed to red. But when I clicked on `watch` button everthing went to black. How can I fix it? Sorry for my english.

here is my vue.js file

```
new Vue({
  el: "#center-element",
  data: {
    homeActive: true,
    watchActive: false,
    groupActive: false,
    gameActive: false,
  },
  methods: {
    homeActiveMethod: function () {
      this.homeActive = true;
      this.watchActive = false;
      this.groupActive = false;
      this.gameActive = false;
    },
    watchActiveMethod: function () {
      this.homeActive = false;
      this.watchActive = true;
      this.groupActive = false;
      this.gameActive = false;
    },
    groupActiveMethod: function () {
      this.homeActive = false;
      this.watchActive = false;
      this.groupActive = true;
      this.gameActive = false;
    },
    watchActiveMethod: function () {
      this.homeActive = false;
      this.watchActive = false;
      this.groupActive = false;
      this.gameActive = true;
    },
  },
});
```

html

```
<ul class="navbar-nav nav nav-tabs mx-auto text-center" id="center-element">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" style="border: none;">
                        <button v-on:click="homeActiveMethod" class="btn" v-bind:class="{active: homeActive}" 
                        id="center-btn-nav">
                            <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" style="border: none;">
                        <button v-on:click="watchActiveMethod" class="btn" v-bind:class="{active: watchActive}"
                         id="center-btn-nav">
                            <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>   
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" style="border: none;">
                        <button class="btn" id="center-btn-nav">
                            <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" style="border: none;">
                        <button class="btn" id="center-btn-nav">
                            <i class="fas fa-gamepad"></i>
                        </button>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

css

```
.active{
    color: red;
    border-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You have two methods called `watchActiveMethod`. One of them should be called `gameActiveMethod`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Vue, you do not need to use `<a>` tags. Remove them and it will probably work.

By the way, you could significantly reduce the amount of code in your Vue component by using a single variable for currently active link:

```js
  data: {
    activeLink: ""
  },
  methods: {
    setActiveLink(activeLink) {
      this.activeLink = activeLink;
    }
  },
```

```html
<button v-on:click="setActiveLink('home')" class="btn" v-bind:class="{active: activeLink === 'home'}" id="center-btn-nav">
```

I would also suggest generating your `<li>` tags using a `v-for` directive.